C How does type conversion work when comparing EOF and chars?
From this SO answer it is my understanding that the following C code is bad practice because declaring c as a char will make a char like 0xFF and the EOF constant indistinguishable.
char c;

while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {   
    ...
}

However in this SO answer detailing the type conversion process when two integral operands of different types are being operated on (in this case with !=), the two types are converted to a common type. Typically to the type with more bits.
Question 1:
Why then if the char 0xFF was found in a file would it not be converted to type int, and then compared to EOF?
Question 2:
In a case where the char 0xFF, or, in binary, 1111 1111 is converted to an int (let's say 16 bits for simplicity), does it then become 0000 0000 1111 1111? If so, would a signed char lose its sign and change in decimal value from -1 to 255?

The library function int getchar() returns int. So you need int char; so that you can distinguish EOF from a data byte.

It's implementation defined (i.e. up to the compiler) if char is a signed or unsigned type. If it's an unsigned type, then the int value EOF (-1) will not be equal to the (unsigned) char value of 255. And this problem happens because almost everywhere a type smaller than int is used (like in a comparison), it will be promoted to an int.

The point is that 0xFF may in fact be found in the file, but it is never returned as anything but 0xFF (least-significant eight bits set), instead of the EOF constant, which is all bits set. And hence, why getchar() returns an int and not a char.

It doesn't matter how EOF converts to char type. A char has typically 256 different values, and one of those values will collide with EOF. You must use int c;.

@WeatherVane: you said "So you need int char;" — presumably, you meant "So you need int c;"?

See while ((c = getc(file)) != EOF) loop won't stop executing.

@JonathanLeffler I did mean int c; as in my later comment.


C How does type conversion work when comparing EOF and chars?

The char object is converted to an int, retaining it value.  That value is then compared aginst EOF (some negative int value).


Question 1: Why then if the char 0xFF was found in a file would it not be converted to type int, and then compared to EOF?

When 0xFF (All 8 bits set) is found in the file, it is read as an unsigned char (as all are bytes are) by getchar() and then returned as an int with the value of 255.


Question 2: In a case where the char 0xFF, or, in binary, 1111 1111 is converted to an int (let's say 16 bits for simplicity), does it then become 0000 0000 1111 1111? If so, would a signed char lose its sign and change in decimal value from -1 to 255?

Instead of thinking in bit patterns, think in terms of values to better understand conversions.
If char is signed, char 0xFF is a -1 and converting that to an int retains the value of -1.
If char is unsigned, char 0xFF is 255 and converting that to an int retains the value of 255.
char is signed or unsigned and that is implementation defined.
Both cases are reasonable possible in 2024.

Key: getchar() typically returns 1 of 257 different int values: 0 to 255 and EOF.  EOF is some negative value.  Saving the return value of getchar() into a char loses something as 257 different values cannot be encoded in an 8-bit char, signed char and unsigned char.  Best to save the int return type  and value as an int.

That are additional issues when UCHAR_MAX > INT_MAX  (e.g. both 32-bit), yet leave that for later discussion.

OP asks about conversion and compare involving EOF, yet that is not the real issue as going from char to int is typically a widening of the type.
The real issues is char c; ... c = getchar() where an int is saved as a char.  That narrowing is where the issues exist as the destination type may be signed or `unsigned_ and it is bound to lose information.

This answer as well as @EricPostpischil 's were helpful, is there anyway to accept both? Thanks!


Question 1: Why then if the char 0xFF was found in a file would it not be converted to type int, and then compared to EOF?

getchar returns an int value. This int value is either an unsigned char value for a character read from the stream or it is the value of EOF. Either way, when comparing it to EOF, the comparison is an int to an int, and there is no conversion, and the desired result of the comparison is produced.
However, your source code does not compare the return value of getchar to EOF. It assigns the value to c. Since c is a char, the value is converted to char. If char is signed in the C implementation, this conversion may change the value of a character. If char is unsigned, this conversion will change the value from EOF. Then your program compares the result of the assignment to EOF. The result of an assignment is not the right operand but is the value after conversion to the type of the left operand. So your source code may be comparing a changed value to EOF, and that is why it is wrong.

Question 2: In a case where the char 0xFF, or, in binary, 1111 1111 is converted to an int (let's say 16 bits for simplicity), does it then become 0000 0000 1111 1111? If so, would a signed char lose its sign and change in decimal value from -1 to 255?

In a C implementation where char is unsigned, assigning 255 to a char will produce the unchanged value 255 in the char, and then converting that back to int will produce 255.
In a C implementation where char is signed, assigning 255 to a char will most commonly produce the value −1 in the char. (The C standard says there is either an implementation-defined result or an implementation-defined signal, but wrapping modulo 256 is the most implementation choice.) Then converting that char back to int will produce −1.
In both cases, the conversion from char to int does not change the value. The loss, if any, occurs when int is converted to char.

This was helpful thank you. I'm not sure if there's a way to accept 2 answers.
